# merge hook for passing all tests without merge request

Tags: git, testing, build, continuous-integration, bitbucket

Our team most of the time will push directly to develop, it will be merged and then trigger Jenkin to run tests. If all tests pass, then it will be automatically built to Alpha users. I wonder if its possible to have a merge hook where all tests must pass before it gets merged into develop. This way, other programmers will not check out broken code. Or maybe this is not a necessary concern at all.

Comment: You have this tagged for "Bitbucket", but are you asking about BB Server (on-prem) or BB Cloud (bitbucket.org)? Both have this available under "merge checks".

Answer (score 2):

The way a lot of teams handle this is to protect the target branch. In Bitbucket, it's called a merge check; in Github it's called a protected branch.

You'd transition from developers pushing directly to master, to developers opening pull requests against master, then add a merge check for a passing CI test build. In this world, you can't merge a commit into develop unless it has a passing test suite.

[Suggest or require checks before a merge](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/suggest-or-require-checks-before-a-merge-856691474.html)